# How to $or query for a term in either two arrays or a string field in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am having difficulty figuring out how the MongoDB $or operator works.

I have three fields in a schema which could contain a search term: (I want to return the document if it is a part match in either one of the arrays, or if it is in the string 'genericName')

e.g:

```
{
genericName: "atenolol",
indications: ["heart attack","angina","hypertension"],
brandNames: ["atenolol GMA", "APRAXA", "Atenolol ASP Brand"]
}
```

and I query with:

```
const searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm; (say "atenolol")
const result =  await db.drugs.find({ $or: [ 
    {"genericName": {$regex : searchTerm}}, 
    {"brandNames": {$regex : searchTerm}}, 
    {"indications" : {$regex : searchTerm}} 
]}
```

result always comes back as []...

A simple find({}) will return documents OK. But I am not sure how to get the $or operator to find a document with a match either in a string array or from a string field..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those with this kind of issue in the future, the $regex command in mongodb is case sensitive.
If you need to pass a field into a query you need to do this including the i for case insensitive:

```
const response = await DrugLookups.find({ $or: [
            {genericName: new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i')},
            {brandNames: new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i')},
            {indications: new RegExp(searchTerm, 'i')},
        ]
        })
```